# mod-rewrite exception? keep #hash in matching urls?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hey guys,
My WordPress permalink structure is set to `/%postname%/.

When I create a page with a name "FAQs" the permalink generated is "mydomain.com/faqs".

When I link to this page in my code (hardcoded) like this...

`<a href="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/faqs#b" title="FAQ's">FAQs</a>` (pay attention to the #b hash at the end)

...wordpress somehow automatically notices that there is a page `/faqs` and replaces `/faqs#b` just with `/faqs` (without the hash).

Is there a chance I can write a kind of exception to my .htaccess file so WordPress doesn't do that?

Any idea how I could make that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your permalink structure is `/%postname%/` with a trailing slash, you need to pass the hash like this: `/faqs/#b` with the trailing slash.

Answer (score 2):

The URL *hash* (everything after the `#`) does not get sent to the server, so Apache or WordPress can't detect it.

WordPress redirects all URLs to the *canonical* version of the URL, to make sure everyone uses the same URL when linking to a post (which can help increase your ranking in search engines). This causes a redirect from `/faqs` to `/faqs/`. [Browsers should append the `#hash` part to the redirected URL, but it seems IE does not do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283395/url-hash-is-persisting-between-redirects).

You can prevent a redirect by using the canonical URL in the URL, like Milo suggested. So link to `/faqs/#b` and it should work.